# Maintaining the Current Style of the Command Prompt After Using 'su?'

Tags: osx, prompt, su

When I use the `su` command in OS X's Terminal — say, to quickly switch to an administrator account to mount a drive using `diskutil` — the style of the command prompt changes.  Before using `su`, the Terminal's Darwin `bash` prompt displays my computer's name as dictated by the part of `$HOSTNAME` which precedes the part of that text string which reads `.local`, a colon, the current working directory, a space, the current user's name, and, finally, a dollar sign.  *After* running `su`, all that's displayed is `bash-3.2$`.  Is there a command that I could run to revert this without undoing my use of `su`?

Comment: look for `PS1` in `man bash`

Comment: That says that `$PS1` is an environment variable.  Running `echo $PS1` without invoking `su` outputs `\h:\W \u\$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `su -l $USERNAME` via Terminal to log in as another user without losing your current prompt style.

Answer (score 3):

Better idea might be to use `sudo` instead of `su`. The prompt change is important because it reminds you that you have elevated privileges and could easily accidentally break something, so you should be careful.

Comment: I usually do this from a standard user account, and, at least in OS X and probably in most Unixes, these kinds of accounts aren't members of the `sudoers` group by default.  I'm OK if the prompt changes to reflect that I'm using a different user account, but I'd rather have the prompt's _style_ remain the same.  OS X's default prompt contains the name of the account you're currently logged into, so I think that should be fine.

Comment: You could add yourself to the `sudoers` group or edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: _Should_ a standard user be a member of the `sudoers` group, though?

Comment: Sure, why not? It's your way of telling the system you're not just a "standard user", you're a user who should be allowed sudo access.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm not sure if I'm comfortable with the idea of giving a non-administrator account the ability to use the `sudo` command.  Doing so sounds like a security risk tantamount to just turning my standard user account into a full-blown admin one, and I don't like the idea of exposing my data like that.

Comment: How is this different from leaving the root shell open so long that you care about the prompt?At that point, you're pretty comfortable in it. IMHO, in this situation, your goal is not to protect against malicious users but rather protect from your own mistakes. After all, you probably care more about your actual data, which doesn't require admin access. So having your user in the `sudoers` group makes you type `sudo` in front of commands to be run as root.

Comment: I'm not switching to the root shell, though; I'm switching to an _admin_ shell!  And I thought that it might be unusual to allow a non-administrative user access to the `sudo` command's powers.

Comment: @SteveWillis:  See the comment above; I think I forgot to '@'-mention you in it…

Comment: I guess I missed the detail that you were using a non-admin account normally. This seems like overkill to me. But as far as the prompt goes, you can set it by setting the `PS1` environment variable. Just set it the same in the elevated shell as what you have in the other shell.

Comment: @SteveWillis:  That's what it is by default in OS X, but, for some _weird_ reason, `su` seems to _ignore_ this default!  How do I fix _that?_

Comment: @SteveWillis:  Maybe there's something in `su`'s `man` page that'll tell me how?

Comment: @RandomDSdevel Try: `export PS1='%m%# '` (or whatever the `PS1` value is for the shell you want to match, check `echo ${PS1}` to see.)

Comment: @SteveWillis:  That may not be necessary, actually.  I just looked up `su`'s `man` page, and it says that `su -l` will 'simulate a full login.'  I tested this, and it worked!

Comment: @SteveWillis:  By the way, I've added the procedure described above to this question as another answer.